# How to stop changing geojson polyline strokeColor to default when other polyline is clicked?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, web, google-maps-api-3, gis

I have plotted/drawn a geojson file on google map using javascript.
The geojson file contains more than one polyline(roads)
I have styled all the polylines using the following JavaScript code.

```
Var myGeojsonLayer = new google.maps.Data();
myGeojsonLayer.loadGeoJson('Local Geojson layer path');

myGeojsonLayer.setStyle(function (feature) {
    return {
        strokeColor: 'green'
    };
});
```

I have registered click listener on the the polylines. 
I change strokeColor of the polyline when it is clicked (change from green to red). But the problem is, the other polylines (which are not clicked)
also change its strokeColor from green(which is initial color) to **default** color(black).
     How to fix this problem, please help me.

```
 myGeojsonLayer.addListener('click', function(event) {

   this.setStyle(function (feature) {

        if(  feature.getProperty('District') == 'Swat'  ){
            return {
                strokeColor: 'red'                  
            };
        }

    });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to be specific regarding the selection of polyline so that the color could be change specifically.

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581669/how-to-change-polyline-color-by-clicking-on-it)